# Strange behaviour of params.append with axios

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, form-data, urlsearchparams

```
export const getCharactersAsync = createAsyncThunk('getCharactersAsync', async (data) => {
  const response = await axios.get('users', { params: { limit: data.limit } });
  return response.data;
});
```

this code block allows me to control limit attribute.

```
export const getCharactersAsync = createAsyncThunk('getCharactersAsync', async (data) => {
  const params = new FormData();
  // const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('limit', data.limit);
  const response = await axios.get('users', params);
  console.log(response);
  return response.data;
});
```

However I cannot control limit with using params.append. I tried URLSearchParams instead of FormData but still cannot manipulate limit attribute of the response. Why they differ from each other?

EDIT: This question has missleading information. I should have mention that i am using react-native. I found that react native doesn't fully support everything the web supports. So i need to install package called `react-native-url-polyfill`.Here is a github issues link
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23922#issuecomment-648096619

Comment: I see that the url has the limit in the first one. The second one shows me that only base url.

Comment: Yes i am sure. I directly copy pasted my code to here. It is not the end of the world i can use the working one. However i try to understand why the other one not working.

Comment: I changed to ```URLSearchParams```. It still shows me the base url.

Answer (score 1):

[docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config)

> `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request. Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object

It can't be `FormData`

### Solution

You wanted to use `{ params }`, not `params`

```
export const getCharactersAsync = createAsyncThunk('getCharactersAsync', async (data) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('limit', data.limit);
  const response = await axios.get('users', { params });
  console.log(response);
  return response.data;
});
```

Comment: As you can see there is a comment line on the second code block which shows that i tried to use URLSearchParams

Comment: thank you for response. I tried your solution and it still gives me default limit number.

Comment: Works fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-babbage-iuvhd9?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Okay clearly there's something else wrong. I try to fix it and edit. Thanks again for the help !

Comment: Thanks for help @Kondrad Linkowski, your solution is correct. I updated my question and added possible answer.